# Allow CORS globally with CorsRegistry or CorsFilter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-security-rest

I have a Springboot backend through which I am exposing some endpoints.

I need to access this from my frontend. When I did so I got an error saying `Invalid CORS request`. Fair enough.
I enabled Cross origin request globally on my backend as mentioned in this [doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/). Code snippet below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("*").allowedOrigins("My-frontend-Host-url");
  }
}
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work. I get the same error. But I managed to get this working using `CorsFilter` as below

```
@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("My-frontend-Host-url");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
  }
```

So what exactly is the difference between these two approaches and why isn't it working in the first case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not checked, but according to the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE_to_4.2.2.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html) you may change the path pattern from `registry.addMapping("*")` to `registry.addMapping("/**")`

> If no path pattern is specified, cross-origin request handling is mapped to "/**".